# Can an Apache Beam batch process be restarted from a checkpoint?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a long-running Apache Beam batch analysis process on Google Cloud Dataflow that failed partway through.  To save time and cost, is it possible to update my code to handle the failure, and re-run from the failure point using cached intermediate checkpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow batch pipelines discard all intermediate results when the pipeline terminates (successfully or fails).

Currently you would need to add points within the pipeline where the intermediate data is materialized and then on failure you could launch a new pipeline which is a subset of your existing pipeline that reads the intermediate results and continues processing.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.  As a thought experiment: if this were needed on every PTransform, the PTransforms would be just passing around filenames in place of data.  Each transform would check for output existence: if output didn't exist, read input files and write output; in all cases, just emit output filename.  Book-keeping would need to be done via filename convention.  Seems like there must be a better approach.

Comment: Since GroupByKey is a typical materialization point within many runners, it could be possible to have checkpoints based upon which GroupByKeys have been written to but not successfully read. This would make it *free* from the execution point since you aren't writing the data when not needed but does limit where you can resume from.

Comment: Interesting point. One other thought I had was to write a decorator (I'm in python) that would handle cacheing by doing pre-lookup or post-storage of data in a db or filesystem. It would give me find grained control of what to cache, and I could pass along lightweight ids of cached objects until a uncached transformation happens. I would need to implement object keys and cache keys in such a way that I can make each transformation unique -- but I desire that for other reasons, as well. Do you think this could be feasible?

Comment: I think so, there is a bunch of work going on to get an interactive Beam runner and it has to solve a lot of these replayability/caching issues as well (but typically with smaller datasets). It might be worth reaching out to the folks on https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e43524e26807a9cb5f90842af1a2408ec410a7c2a7eaedc2add2f1fc@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E about it.